# we didn't have much in terms of looking at that hypothesis

Tags: phrase-meaning

"We didn't have much in terms of looking at that hypothesis" - didn't have much what? Didn't have much time, energy or facts?

It appears to be ambiguous to me.

> Yes, lab accidents do happen around the world; they have happened in the past. The fact that several laboratories of relevance are in and around Wuhan, and are working with coronavirus, is another fact. Beyond that **we didn't have much in terms of looking at that hypothesis** as a likely option.

> Source:  Science  ['Politics was always in the room.' WHO mission chief reflects on China trip seeking COVID-19’s origin
> By Kai KupferschmidtFeb. 14, 2021](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2021/02/politics-was-always-room-who-mission-chief-reflects-china-trip-seeking-covid-19-s)

Answer (score 1):

> **For each hypothesis, we tried to** put facts on the table, **look at what
> we had in terms of arguments,** and then make an assessment of each. It
> was already a big step to have Chinese colleagues assess and evaluate
> such a hypothesis based on what we had on the table, which was not
> much. Yes, lab accidents do happen around the world; they have
> happened in the past. The fact that several laboratories of relevance
> are in and around Wuhan, and are working with coronavirus, is another
> fact. Beyond that **we didn't have much in terms of looking at that
> hypothesis as a likely option**.

I agree that the speaker does not seem to be a great English stylist. But in context, his words seems to mean that there was little reason to believe that hypothesis.